# Could not read from remote repository error.What to do?

Tags: git, github

I created a repository on my local machine. 
I tried to push it to github
`git push origin master`
I added the remote repository.
`git remote add origin git@github.com:.... .git`
But when I push to the repository it gives an error

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[Error Message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLl95.jpg)

- I removed all the ssh keys from github
- This is a private repository

Comment: I removed all the ssh keys from github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to push via ssh. Missing pub key on the remote or missing private key in the ~/.ssh dir will result in an error. Try using the https protocol. `git remote add origin https://github.com/{username}/{repo}.git`, then push as usual. Good luck! :)

Comment: didn't see you already answered yout question. :D Glad u figured it out.

Comment: @Vinay666 Upvoting a question means _“This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear”_. I'm not sure which of these attributes applies to yours. However. Talking someone into upvoting a question isn't considered best practice here, especially if you neither upvoted the answer yourself nor accepted it.

Comment: I figured it out myself and I posted the answer but it says "you can accept your answer in 2 days"  https://imgur.com/a/rSrexHD

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I am behind our institute proxy server(HTTP proxy server - IIT KGP). Which does not allow git protocol.I changed `git remote add origin git@github.com:.... .git` to `git remote https://github.com/......git` and it worked.Thanks to our institute proxy I am able to post a question and answer on ask ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

for update URL repository in git use this command:

git remote set-url origin ssh://git@host:port<workspace_ID>/<repo_name>.git